# Тестирование средствами Jest и Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jest, enzyme

Как я могу тестировать этот фрагмент кода с помощью Jest+Enzyme?

```
export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return bindActionCreators(
     {
       addOrderForBuy,
       addOrderForSell,
       loadOrdersForBuy,
       loadOrdersForSell,
       loadHistoryOfDeal,
     },
     dispatch
   );
};
```

Пример моего кода:

```
 describe('mapDispatchToProps', () => {
  const dispatch = jest.fn();
  const actions = mapDispatchToProps(dispatch);
  // что-то ожидается в expect-ах...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Сначала нужно посмотреть на то, что вы хотите тестировать:

```
export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return bindActionCreators(
     {
       addOrderForBuy,
       addOrderForSell,
       loadOrdersForBuy,
       loadOrdersForSell,
       loadHistoryOfDeal,
     },
     dispatch
   );
};
```

тут я вижу простую функцию, которая принимает один параметр `dispatch` и далее внутри вызывает метод `bindActionCreators`, в котором, как я понимаю, привязывает переданное значение в параметре к некоторому объекту. Тип данных должен быть у переданного параметра функцией.

Далее, идет написание теста, импорты мы *опустим* и сразу перейдем к написанию теста:

```
describe('mapDispatchToProps', () => {
  // создаем переменную, которую передадим в функцию
  const dispatch = jest.fn();

  // вызовем тестируемый метод
  const result = mapDispatchToProps(dispatch);

  // далее опишем несколько ожидаемых результатов
  // некоторые из них могут показаться слишком примитивными

  it('toHaveBeenCalledTimes', () => {
    // ожидается, что наша функция была вызвана один раз  
    expect(mapDispatchToProps).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('toHaveBeenCalledWith', () => {
    // ожидается, что наша функция была вызвана с параметром dispatch
    expect(mapDispatchToProps).toHaveBeenCalledWith(dispatch);
  });

  it('objectContaining', () => {
    // ожидается, что в результирующем объекте будет содержаться переданный параметр  
    expect(result).toEqual(expect.objectContaining(dispatch));
  });
})
```

Вообще **Enzyme** - утилита тестирования JavaScript для React, которая упрощает тестирование ваших компонентов React. В данном примере у Вас просто функция, поэтому Enzyme в этом тесте не использовался.

**Jest** - это фреймворк для тестирования кода JavaScript и React-приложений. Но React компонент тут нет, и я использовал простые функции для тестирования предоставленного кода.

Что у **Enzyme**, что у **Jest** - есть очень хорошая документация с кучей примеров, поэтому даю ссылки, чтобы было куда заглядывать (в случае, если вы не смогли найти их самостоятельно):

- [Enzyme](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/)
- [Jest](https://jestjs.io/)
- [Jest Expect](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect)
- [Enzyme API Reference](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/)